# Multi-master репликация MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, репликация

Для двух хостов все просто: указываю для первого хотся второй в качестве головного сервера, а для второго - первый (с помощью команды SQL change master to master_host..).

Появилась необходимость настроить репликацию для системы из 4 хостов.
Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Comment: Это называется не "Multi-master", а "master-master" репликация. Создание же сетки репликации для 4 хостов невозможно, репликация в MySQL умеет оперировать только единственным мастером. Можете попытаться создать кольцо репликации (первый является мастером второго, тот мастером третьего, он мастером четвёртого, который будет мастером первого).

Comment: Хотя если у Вас NDB - то тогда всё по мануалу. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Остановился на NDB кластере, так как разворачивать БД только собираемся. Буду тестировать.